# Is it possible to implement the effect of overflow:ellipsis with javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show `...` when `overflow` happens,

but sadly in css there is only `overflow:hidden` which is near but not exact what I want.

Is it possible to implement it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow. Doesn't support Firefox, however.

---

Edit: There's a [jQuery plugin](http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/) for this. After you have installed it, call

```
$(thatElement).ellipsis();
```

to activate the style. See http://jsbin.com/acuti3. There are a [bunch of other jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/ellipsis) for besides this.

Comment: Support all other browsers other than firefox? Anyway, I don't want to give up firefox..

Answer (score 1):

[-moz-binding](http://www.rikkertkoppes.com/thoughts/2008/6/) > firefox
-o-text-overflow > opera
text-overflow > ie + webkit (chrome/safari)

Comment: It looks like -moz-binding won't be supported in Firefox 4: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546857

Comment: @joril at least `text-overflow: ellipsis` [will be supported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312156)

Comment: wow, a 6-year-old feature request :) Well better late than never I guess :)