# CSS: How to limit text shown with using "..."

Tags: html, css, web-applications, trim

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it possible to implement the effect of overflow:ellipsis with javascript or css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995656/is-it-possible-to-implement-the-effect-of-overflowellipsis-with-javascript-or-cs)
>   [How do I indicate long text into a smaller fixed column with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108740/how-do-i-indicate-long-text-into-a-smaller-fixed-column-with-css)

I want to trim text if it's greater than 300px wide with "..."

For example, if I had:

```
<ul>
<li>this is greater than 300px, than only display as much of the text that is 300px wide and then replace the remaining text with "..."</li>
<li>short, don't trim</li>
</ul>
```

Would display as:

```
this is greater than 300px, than only ...
short, don't trim
|----------- 300px wide ----------------|
```

How would I do that with CSS/HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement the effect of overflow:ellipsis with javascript or css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995656/) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067696 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486563/ man I am bored of this question

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't work using **pure** CSS/HTML. It only worked if I used JQuery and I don't want to use JQuery.

Comment: **This might be a duplicate BUT I haven't found a pure CSS/HTML answer that WORKS. There has been suggestions to use code like linked but that code does NOT work.**  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108740/how-do-i-indicate-long-text-into-a-smaller-fixed-column-with-css/2109035#2109035